# SP Services - Limit, display top 10 from list (Latest IDs)

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, spservices, splistitem

The current script creates a table showing all Items from the list.

What I want to achieve is to:
Limit the items to ONLY show latest top 10 IDs in the table.

e.g. If I have a list of 21 Items, it should display ID number 11 to 21 (Latest Top 10), sorted by ascending order.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> get() ;function get() { var method = "GetListItems";                
var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                    
var list = "Core Libraries";                     
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";                  

$().SPServices
({ operation: method, async: false, webURL: webURL, listName: list,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
CAMLQuery: query, completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
{ var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
var update  =  $(this).attr("ows_Update");
var date  =  $(this).attr("ows_Date");

$("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
"<td align='left'>"+date+"</td>" + "<td align='left'>"+update+"</td>" + "</tr>");

}); } }); };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CamlRowLimit to get the top 10 results:

```
CAMLQuery: query,
CAMLRowLimit: 10,
```